# How to copy test case from one suite to another in FitNesse?

Tags: wiki, fitnesse

I have 2 test suites created in the FrontPage, lets say Suite1 and Suite2. Now I have 1 test case created in Suite1, lets say TestCase1, and would like to have another copy of TestCase1 inside Suite2, may I know how can I use the "Recfactor" feature in the FitNesse to "copy" TestCase1 into Suite2?

Thanks @!

Comment: what you mean with another copy? Running the same tests from both suite or having another test with the same name?

Comment: My objective is to move the TestCase1 from Suite1 to Suite2, if FitNesse unable to do that, at least I can copy from Suite1 to Suite2 then delete the TestCase1 from Suite1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your suites Suite1 and Suite2 have been created directly on FrontPage.

To **move** a TestCase1 from Suite1 to Suite2 you can simply click on refactor link of TestCase1 page or open this link: http://localhost:8000/FrontPage.Suite1.TestCase1?refactor

Then enter FrontPage.Suite2 in "New Location" field under **MOVE** section. And then click on Move Page button. Now your TestCase1 has been moved under Suite2 from Suite1.